# PHP code of parent method add to child method with working return statement

Tags: php

I have BaseClass. I have method BaseMethod in it, which has some if..else structure.

I want to use if..else of BaseMethod in child methods to avoid repeating of code.

But when I use parent::BaseMethod() I'm not receiving desirable result, because `return` of BaseMethod() not work.

*In other words I want to chain the functions together.  If the parent method does not evaluate so as to return a result I want to continue into the child's method.*

Example, what I want:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public function BaseMethod($baseVariable)
    {
        if($baseVariable == 1) {
           return 'something'; // I want this work in my base method
        }
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    public function BaseMethod($baseVariable)
    {
        parent::BaseMethod($baseVariable);
        if($baseVariable == 3) {
           return 'one more something';
        }
    }
}
$a = new BaseClass();
$b = new ChildClass();
echo $a->baseMethod(1); // this is work
echo $b->baseMethod(1); // this is not work
```

Please, help me to complete this task. Thanks a lot for any help!

**UPDATED.** I have edited my code, you can test it with your environment.

Comment: What do you want returned in the 2 cases???

Comment: @AbraCadaver I want to have same result of parent::baseMethod() in child baseMethod().. so, if($baseVariable == 1) should work for child methods..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with this signature: `public function method BaseMethod($baseVariable)`.  Are you under the impression that `method` is a key word?  Are you trying to extend a function like you would a class?

That is not valid PHP syntax.  The following edited code does "work":

```
class BaseClass
{
    public function baseMethod($baseVariable)
    {
        if($baseVariable == 1) {
           return 'something'; // I want this work in my base method
        } elseif (2==1) {
           return 'something else'; // This too
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    public function baseMethod($baseVariable)
    {
        $foo = parent::baseMethod($baseVariable);
        if (!is_null($foo)) return $foo;

        if($baseVariable == 3) {
           return 'one more something';
        } else {
           return 'one more something else';
        }
    }
}
$a = new BaseClass();
$b = new ChildClass();
echo $a->baseMethod(1); // this is work
echo $b->baseMethod(1); // this is not work, because "1" using in parent::baseMethod()
```

**OK.  See updated code.**  Was hard to follow what you were asking.  Think I understand now.

Comment: So you want `childClass` to *inherit* the `baseMethod` of the parent?  Then just remove the function from the child class...If you want to *override* it do what you are doing.  Not sure I get your question.

Comment: no, this is not works. if you would see more attentively, baseMethod of $a and $b return not same result!

Comment: yes, I want to override my method and leave parent if..else work

Comment: but $baseVariable == 1 works only for parent::baseMethod

Comment: can you help me to edit my post, to make it more understandable?

Comment: I'll do that Sergio.  I know language barriers can be tough.

Comment: This will never return `null`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver good point.  Well depending what you pass the function it will... At least managed to convey what we were both alluding to.

Answer (score 2):

If `$baseVariable == 3` then return something, if not then return the parent method:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
    public function BaseMethod($baseVariable)
    {
        if($baseVariable == 3) {
           return 'one more something';
        } else {
           return parent::BaseMethod($baseVariable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I pulled the teeth, but Abra is saying the same thing.